# Accidentally created a never-ending while loop. How can I stop my sim now?

Tags: while-loop, netlogo

Wanted to add an `if` block before a `while` loop but accidentally excluded the part which should increase the variable `repeat-var`.

how can I cancel/stop my simulation without loosing my coding progress?

[I think you can see my mistake..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33ejg.png)

Comment: Device: MacBook Pro

Comment: Program still loading - no answers

Comment: If you can still access the code tab, select all your code and copy it to notepad or something as a failsafe. Then, try "Halt"- I think it's in Tools -> Halt

Comment: I can't access the code tab :/

Comment: Okey, my changes are rip

Comment: Sorry to hear. Happens to everyone at least once! Going forward if you "Halt" early enough you can usually recover.